# Secure Hyper-V-Server with fido2 usb key

Tags: windows, remote-access

I want to set up a new Hyper-V-Server and secure it, so access to the server itself is only possible with physical FIDO2 keys (like YubiKey).

Access using remote desktop should also only be possible with the right Fido2 Keys.

How can I setup a windows server so only certain users with fido2 as 2nd auth can access them?